# How to use Spring Data ElasticSearch with MongoDb

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch, spring-data, gridfs

I am trying to implement full text search on text file stored in database while using `Spring Data`.
`MongoDb` is perfect for searches but it can only store `16Mb` size documents. On the other hand `GridFs` can store larger files but no search is allowed on data it holds.
So the question is:

> 1. What are size limits for Elasticsearch documents and database.(Can I give up on GridFs to store larger files?
> 2. Can I use Spring Data MongoDb and Spring Data Elasticsearch together?(Mongo for common information storage and queries(**MongoRepository**) and Elastic for full-text
>      search on text data stored.

If yes, I would be grateful if anyone could help me to set it up.(sth called **mongo-connector**??) I have already working Spring Data MongoDb in my project. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Lucene uses 32 bits for addressing. In theory you can use 2GB document. But I think you'll face another issues before 2GB not related to Elastic. There are better practices to store big data.
2. You can use [ElasticsearchRepository](https://github.com/azee/elastic-template/blob/master/template-dal/src/main/java/com/mycompany/template/repositories/elastic/SomeBeanElasticRepository.java) from spring data.

See [example project](https://github.com/azee/elastic-template)

Comment: I would like to store like 20Mb files and do full-text-search on them. But the number of files would exceed 2GB. Is it possible to have lots of documents < 2GB size? It would be perfect .

Comment: Sure. As an example - one of my projects uses Mongo and db size is over 2 TB.

Comment: but in Mongo document size can't be more than 16MB :) U use elasticsearch with mongo right?

Comment: I have lots of documents in Mongo. Not so big but a huge amount of them.  I'm using river plugin to combine Mongo and Elastic. Perhaps you shouldn't keep those docs in Mongo? Keep them on a file system on in cloud (Amazon S3) and build indexes in Elastic related to file ids.

Comment: Good. My intention is to store txt files like up to 20MB and do full txt search on them. Rest of the info would be stored in MongoDb. As I understand, this is reasonable approach?